# In my UNO WASM project HTTP POST calls become HTTP OPTIONS on my local Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, uno-platform, webassembly

My HTTP Post calls work as expected from my UWP and Droid projects but when I make the same call from my WASM project Azure Functions sees the call as OPTIONS and not POST. I read it's a CORS issue and I needed to add a local.settings.json file to my Azure Functions project. It now looks like this:

```
{
  "Values": {

  },
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

I still experience the same issue. It's not the HTTP call since it works from the other platforms in UNO.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Thanks Chris. Could you include some code that shows how you're invoking this Azure Function from your app ?

Comment: As you have partially figured out...there is a "pre flight" "options" check.     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request#:~:text=A%20CORS%20preflight%20request%20is,Headers%20%2C%20and%20the%20Origin%20header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The problem

That's the *magic* of the CORS mecanism. This call is called a **CORS preflight** and it's used to check with the server if the call is authorized by the server.

### Why you have CORS problems

Since WebAssembly (WASM) applications are running inside a browser, they can't escape all the security systems present in a browser. Http calls are actually done by browsers using the [`fetch` api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) by the `WasmHttpHandler`.

Most of the time, this happened when you are making calls on a different hostname that your application.  Let's say you deploy your Wasm application on `https://mybikeisyellow.app/` and doing *REST* calls to `https://myneightborbikeisred.biz`, the browser will first make an `OPTIONS` call to `https://myneightborbikeisred.biz` before allowing any other non-`GET` call to be made there.

### More about CORS

You can search on the Internet about CORS, there's plenty of very useful information on why it's there and how to manage it.  I found [this one](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-cors) pretty well done.

### How to solve your problem

**For your specific problem** in Azure Fuctions, follow [this guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/handling-cors-in-azure-function/) and you'll be able to make it accept your requests.